# in Edit form radio button not checked as per value in angular2

Tags: angular

in Edit form radio button not checked as per value
I got the last name from the database but when i try to bind gender with radio button then its not shown checked

```
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !firstname.valid }">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" [(ngModel)]="employee.last_name" #lastname="ngModel" required />
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !firstname.valid" class="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !gender.valid }">
                <label for="lastname">Gender</label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" [value]="Male" [ngModel]="{checked: employee.gender == 'Male'}">Male
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Female
                </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have ngModel on only `male`? Do you actually get a value for `employee.gender` from DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]="employee.gender == 'Male'">Male
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                         <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]="employee.gender == 'Female'">Female
                    </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work!

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender"  name="sex" value="Male">Male> </input>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [value] instead of value

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender"  name="sex" [value]="Male">Male </input>
```

Comment: what does employee.gender has ? did you tried my answer